# Footnote is placed below instead above key word?

Tags: footnotes, subscripts

Thanks for all the assistance so far! You're great! :D

anyway I have a problem that when using the footnote command `\footnote` the footnote number is placed subscripted to the key word instead of superscript... anybody might know why? I'm working in sharelatex if that any help...

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{etex} 
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{dsfont} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage[hang,bottom,stable,multiple]{footmisc} 
\usepackage{appendix} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[margin=10pt, font=small, labelfont=bf, labelsep=endash]{caption}
\usepackage{chngcntr} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{thmtools} 
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{datetime} 
\usepackage{graphicx,listings,xcolor,textcomp} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{xparse} 
\usepackage{cleveref} 
\usepackage{arydshln} 
\usepackage{array,hhline} 
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{morefloats}
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\graphicspath{{Images/}}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={((},close={))}}
\begin{document}
Usually the Monte Carlo Simulation\footnote{blablablablabla}is used to blabla.

\end{document}
```

The foot note is noted as a subscript instead as a superscript... any ideas why?

Comment: The fact that you're using ShareLaTeX is actually irrelevant, most likely. A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) is more helpful.

Comment: As it stands, I'm really not seeing this as a question at all: as well as a MWE, could you make it clear what is the idea here?

Comment: @JosephWright The number for footnotes is shown as subscripts rather than superscripts, as I understand it.

Comment: The code doesn't show footnote numbers as subscripts. Please make a MWE that *shows* the strange behaviour.

Comment: The *not so* minimal working example works fine for me.